# What does 'genau' mean in colloquial language?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase

There are a few young German students at my university and when they speak in German I noticed they often say 'genau' or 'ja, genau' in response to a statement made by someone else.  Is this something like 'Exactly' in response to a statement or 'Yeah, right'.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is suited for this website. A simple dictionary (or google translate) would have answered to you that "genau" does in fact mean "exactly". Imagine if everyone asked single word translations here

Comment: It is the same as responding with „exactly“ or „precise“. It may have a sub notion of „told you already“ or „exactly my point“ or „finally you got it“

Comment: @IvoBeckers In this case, *no* major dictionary explains the rather large portion of colloquial use where the meaning  is *reversed*. Translating (written down) spoken language might get funny results if one were to rely on what a search engine spits out.

Comment: Ther's absolutely nothing colloquial in that.

Comment: I could have looked in a dictionary, but it seemed to be like there were different shades of meaning to the word depending on how it is said.  Obviously the only way for me to know what those 'shades' are is to ask people who speak the language, what else am I supposed to do?

Comment: @tofro Why not? Translating a solemn & official speech containing that word is served well with just the dictionary. Understanding the banter among students making outrageous claims that are answered with that word will prove a dictionary to be worthless.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, *Genau!* is just an affirmative response, which literally translates to *exactly*, meaning *It is exactly as you said* and could well be translated into *Right!*, *Correct!*.

Comment: This is interesting, thanks, it makes me want to learn German but I feel like I am just too busy.

Comment: Lol. I can understand how a single word can make you want to learn a language. For me, it was "Bier" ;-)

Comment: For me it was Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaftskapitän, making me want to learn my native language.

Comment: I hear this as an affirmative filler word all the time.

Answer (score 15):

That pretty much depends on tone of voice.

*Genau*, used in normal voice means "exactly". Almost just a filler with confirmatory intent. Factual agreement. That is probably the most often heard case, and the usually the only [one](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/genau_exakt_eben_so) [that](https://www.dwds.de/wb/genau) [dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/deutsch-englisch/genau) [tell](https://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/genau.html) [you](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/genau) [about](https://en.langenscheidt.com/german-english/genau).

> So, I gather from this observation that the sun is at the center of our solar system? – [Genau](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Genau).

But *genau* used in a sarcastic/ironic/sardonic voice has to be translated differently. Often the last syllable is signalling hysterical content by being raised, more melodic than usual and/or somewhat stretched. Or like @Marv commented: "The second is also true when it‘s spoken something like ‚genauuu‘ (or „ge-nauuu“), meaning with a dragged out ‚u‘."

In that case it is more or of the "Yeah, right" or "can't be serious", or even "you're pulling my leg!", "nonsense". Then it is not "exactly", but the exact opposite!

> So, I know since childhood that the moon is what we call the sun at night. – *'Ge-nau'*

Comment: The second is also true when it‘s spoken something like „genauuu“ (or „ge-nauuu“), meaning with a dragged out „u“.

Comment: Right! vs riiiiiight